# Load large file to pdfjs-dist using streams

Tags: node.js, pdf.js, node-streams, pdfjs-dist

Is there anyway to load large files for `pdfjs-dist` package using streams in Node.JS?

currently I don't know a way other than `const data = new Uint8Array(fs.readFileSync(pdfPath));`